# SQL equivalent of MS Access Partition function

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I use Partition function lot for Report in MS Access 2003. I need equivalent of this function for MS SQL.

Here is link about Partition function http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA012288921033.aspx (registration required)

Thanks

Comment: Is this close to what you are asking:  http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/03/28/60146.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Main thing is I would like to be able to add a range.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can see is the [NTILE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx) function, though without a little more context on how you use it, I can't offer anything in the way of a code sample.

Comment: + Thanks. Seems like MSSQL 2005 doesn't have this function.